# Conditional move or copy assignment in ternary operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, ternary-operator, move-semantics, value-categories

For the following code snippet:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#define C(name) (name ? name : "nullptr")
#define PP { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << C(name) << '\n'; }
#define T { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " : " << C(name) << " -> " << C(rhs.name) << '\n'; }

struct A
{
    const char * name = nullptr;
    A(const char * name) : name{name} PP
    A(A && rhs) : name{std::exchange(rhs.name, nullptr)} PP
    A(const A & rhs) : name{rhs.name} PP
    A & operator = (A && rhs) { T; std::swap(name, rhs.name); return *this; }
    A & operator = (const A && rhs) { T; name = rhs.name; return *this; }
    ~A() PP
};

#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device d;
    A a{"a"};
    A b{"b"};
    A c{"c"};
    std::cout << "begin\n";
    a = ((d() % 2) == 0) ? b : std::move(c);
    std::cout << "end\n";
}
```

there are possible two following outputs:

```
A::A(const char*) : a
A::A(const char*) : b
A::A(const char*) : c
begin
A::A(A&&) : c
A& A::operator=(A&&) : a -> c
A::~A() : a
end
A::~A() : nullptr
A::~A() : b
A::~A() : c
```

and

```
A::A(const char*) : a
A::A(const char*) : b
A::A(const char*) : c
begin
A::A(const A&) : b
A& A::operator=(A&&) : a -> b
A::~A() : a
end
A::~A() : c
A::~A() : b
A::~A() : b
```

Is it possible (according to the Standard) for the compiler to avoid using of temporary value during copy/move assignment with ternary operator in the above case and dispatch to copy or move assignment operator to assign the value of right hand side (`b` or `c`) directly to left hand side (`a`) depending on a condition?

Comment: Do you mean `if ((d() % 2) == 0) a = b; else a = std::move(c);`?

Comment: @Evg Yes. Sort of

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible ... for the compiler to avoid using of temporary value during copy/move assignment with ternary operator

This is an interesting question because of the way you have written the code.

In *general*, yes. A compiler is permitted to rearrange or elide code **provided that the *observable result* is the same as if it had executed the code**. This is called the as-if rule.

The compiler is further allowed to elide copies in other circumstances even when there would be a change in observed behaviour, e.g. RVO (return value optimisation).

However in your case, all of the constructors have observable behaviour which cannot be changed - they emit characters to stdout!

So in this particular case, the compiler has no choice but to follow the flow of your original code.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the section on copy/move elision from the draft standard, [[class.copy.elision]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision), which covers which cases copy/move can be elided even if they have side effects. We don't see any cases that cover your example:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move
>   operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object. If the first parameter of the selected
>   constructor is an rvalue reference to the object’s type, the destruction of that object occurs when the target
>   would have been destroyed; otherwise, the destruction occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization.119 This elision of copy/move operations, called copy
>   elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of
>     a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function parameter or a variable introduced by the
>     exception-declaration of a handler (13.3)) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function
>     return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly
>     into the function call’s return object
> - in a throw-expression (7.6.17), when the operand is the name of a non-volatile automatic object
>     (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of
>     the innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from the operand to the
>     exception object (13.1) can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the exception
>     object
> - when the exception-declaration of an exception handler (Clause 13) declares an object of the same
>     type (except for cv-qualification) as the exception object (13.1), the copy operation can be omitted by
>     treating the exception-declaration as an alias for the exception object if the meaning of the program will
>     be unchanged except for the execution of constructors and destructors for the object declared by the
>     exception-declaration. [Note: There cannot be a move from the exception object because it is always an
>     lvalue. —end note]
>
> Copy elision is required where an expression is evaluated in a context requiring a constant expression (7.7)
>   and in constant initialization (6.8.3.2). [Note: Copy elision might not be performed if the same expression is
>   evaluated in another context. —end note]